# Adding to a value throughout a form with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web

I wasn't able to find this specific topic in any of the other StackOverflow questions:

I'm building a decision support page for doctors.

I am very much a beginner to JQuery and I want to create a variable that adds up as users click through a questionnaire. That is, there is a table with questions and the user clicks either "yes" or "no" and for each "yes," a different value is added to the total. For example, "History of alcoholism" might add 4 while "History of depression" might add 2.

Then, at the end, the sum is color coded to "high risk" (>8), "medium risk" (5-8), etc.

I should note that I am using JQuery and JQuery Mobile.

Comment: do you have the html of the form?

Comment: you are in the wrong place

Comment: You need to present code here, not a requirement list and then ask us to build it for you. Since you are new to jQuery you should read some tutorials, Google "jQuery tutorials".

Comment: Are you also a beginner at JavaScript and HTML?  If so, you may want to go through some tutorials first.  And this could easily get complicated.  For instance, I click 'yes' to alcoholism and my score increases by 4, then I click 'no'.  You'll need to track changes like that.  Off-hand, I'd look at using data- attributes in the form fields, and access them via jQuery.  You'd probably want to recalculate the score everytime someone clicks an answer, just to avoid the complication that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Markup

```
<input class=questionaire id="question1" type=checkbox value=1>Question 1<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question2" type=checkbox value=2>Question 2<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question3" type=checkbox value=3>Question 3<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question4" type=checkbox value=2>Question 4<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question5" type=checkbox value=1>Question 5<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question6" type=checkbox value=1>Question 6<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question7" type=checkbox value=3>Question 7<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question8" type=checkbox value=2>Question 8<br>
<input class=questionaire id="question9" type=checkbox value=5>Question 9<br>
<div id=message>
 The color of this changes as the score gets higher, 0 is black, <8 is blue, >8 is red.
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.questionaire').change(function () {
    //sum it up
    var sum = 0;
    $('.questionaire:checked').each(function (index) {

        sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    if (sum == 0) {
        $('#message').attr('style', 'color:black');
    }
    if (sum < 8 and sum > 0) {
        $('#message').attr('style', 'color:blue');
    }
    if (sum > 8) {
        $('#message').attr('style', 'color:red');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you started: use jQuery 1.10.2

```
// Attach a change event listener to all radio buttons on the page
// This means that when you click a radio button then it will go into the function(){} code
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){ // this nifty code says that "anytime a radio button is clicked in the scope of the document then fire off this function" If you plan on dynamically adding radio buttons then make sure to use this format

    //woot, we're in!

    //spit out the value of the changed radio button
    console.log($(this).val()); //or this.value

    // console.log(); is gonna be your very best friend :)
});
```

It is up to you to formulate the rest of the logic, good luck!